# Selenium JavascriptExecutor document.evaluate 'XPathResult': The result type is not a number

Tags: selenium

I'm tring to take first `node` of an div from html using `JavascriptExecutor document.evaluate`

```
String txt = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver)
           .executeScript("return document.evaluate(\"//div[@id = 'SIvCob']/node()[1]\",
                           document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null)").toString();

System.out.print(txt);
```

But I get an error at `executeScript`

```
org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: 
    javascript error: 
        Failed to read the 'numberValue' property from 'XPathResult': 
            The result type is not a number.
```

The `node` I want is a simple text(without html tags or other things)

I'm using ChromeDriver.

Comment: Well for one thing you don’t need the backslashes to escape the quotes surrounding the xpath. Not sure if that will fix it fully but that is definitely an invalid xpath.

Comment: @C.Peck Are you sure? It looks like if the backslashes were removed, then the Java would not even compile.

KunLun, are you saying that you want the Text value of the found element? If so, why not just do "return document.getElementByXPath(\"my xpath expression\").Text; ?

Comment: Yes, you are right, I missed that it was inside the jsexecutor's quotes.

Comment: Can you upload the HTML of the page you are looking at or provide the URL?  That is the easiest/maybe the only way I think you will get a good answer.

Comment: @C.Peck I figured it. I added `stringValue` at `return document.evaluate(...).stringValue` P.S: `document.getElementByXPath` don't exists in javascript.

Comment: Can you please provide the solution in an answer if you've solved it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for my problem was to call `stringValue` at the result of `document.evaluate(...)`.

Like this: `document.evaluate(...).stringValue`